# How to reference to outer member

Tags: javascript, closures

Given following JavaScript code:

```
({
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  zoo: 3,
  test: function(i) {
    var g = function(i) {
        alert(i + zoo);
    }
    g(i);
  }
}).test(2);
```

Why is `zoo` undefined in `alert()`? Which kind of syntax can I use to correctly reference to `zoo` and get alert display for value `5`?

**Update:** I would prefer solution where only implementation of `g` needs to change, if at all possible.

Comment: Try googling "Javascript nested function this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zoo` is not a free floating variable, it's a property of the object. Inside `test` you can reference the object using `this` (because of the way you call it). Inside `g` the `this` context will be lost though, so you need to explicitly preserve it:

```
test: function(i) {
    var g = function(i) {
        alert(i + this.zoo);
    }.bind(this);
    g(i);
}
```

or:

```
test: function(i) {
    var g = function(i) {
        alert(i + this.zoo);
    };
    g.call(this, i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an arrow function to preserve the "outside" value of `this`, and use it to access the value of `zoo` property:

```
({
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  zoo: 3,
  test: function(i) {
    var g = i => alert(i + this.zoo);
    g(i);
  }
}).test(2);
```

Comment: What is the real world compatibility of this syntax? I'm mainly interested in web browsers.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen you can check the compatibility at [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) and the popularity of browsers at [http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp)

Comment: I would really like this but the compatiblity seems poor. I think the closest emulation of that with good compatiblity is `function(...) { ... }.bind(this)`.

Comment: This and any other ES6 feature is going to be need to be transpiled for the foreseeable future, but ES6 offers so many features and so much convenience that it's worth considering adding this step to your build process.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke a member function of an object, the `this` keyword is set to the object (unless you call the function using `.call` or `.apply`). The function `g` is no longer a member of the object, so `this` is not set to the object. You have a couple of options if you want to keep using the `g` function.

Set a reference to `this`:

```
test: function(i) {
    var that = this;
    var g = function(i) {
        alert(i + that.zoo);
    }
    g(i);
}
```

or manually set the value of `this` by using `.call`

```
test: function(i) {
    var g = function(i) {
        alert(i + this.zoo);
    }
    g.call(this, i);
}
```

Here's a little more info about [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: `that` is dead. `self` is dead.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
({
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2,
      zoo: 3,
      test: function(i) {
        var g = function(_this,i) {
            alert(i + _this.zoo);
        }
        g(this,i);
      }
    }).test(2);
```

Comment: That describes a workaround for the problem but does not answer the "why" part.

Comment: for 'why' I agree with @deceze's explanation.